# Recursion questions

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm making a sudoku solver using recursion and I'm having some problems. I put comments next to my vables and functions to try to make this as clear as possible. Does my logic sound like this would work? Everything else in my code works. It's just the solver/recursion it that is not.

```
bo


boourn 
    f nt j=0; j < 9; j++)
    rowc c=0;
           8) //if row is past 8 then the board is done

            return true;


    for (int < 10; i++)
    {

                    nextr r; //save next row and col
                    next;
                    tcol++; /ncrement next col and row
                     (nextcol >8) {
                nextcol =0;
                nx
            if(ncol==0 && nextrow ==9)
    r(0, 0
}
```

Comment: On an initial read, nothing jumps out.  What sort of problem are you having?  Also, where do you initialize the sudoku puzzle?

Comment: Was thinking of posting an answer, but maybe i'll just comment ... your `while` loop is rather redundant ... it does nothing ... just runs through all the cells, and returns true at the end ...

Comment: I added in the code for the constructor. Basically I initialize everything to 0 then I read in the certain values of the puzzle, like row 0, col 2 might be a 5. row 0, col 5, might be a 7. everything else would be 0. Hmmm, I have to have the while loop to go through the columns though. That's a good point now that I think about it I don't think it actually does anything. Any suggestions on how I can fix that?

Comment: @Noctis:  I thought that at first too, but look more closely:  It breaks out when it finds the first unsolved square in the puzzle at or after the starting point that was passed in.  At least, that's what I interpret it as doing.

Comment: @Mdjon26 you should use the `@`+username if you reply to someone here, so  he'll be notified of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `solver` function you provided actually views the whole array, and - provided the other functions used in the code work correctly - should actually solve the puzzle. If you substitute `cout << " TRUE TRUE "<<endl;` for `cout << "["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"]: "<<i<<endl;`, you'll notice all indexes are checked.

So the problem must be in either one of the 3 functions you didn't provide code for: `row_valid`, `col_valid` or `panel_valid`.

**Note:** *I don't think using recursion in this particular problem is a good idea. You probably should just do it using a `for` to check and solve the board. That would be both faster and easier.*

### Edit after first post was updated

The `row_valid` and `col_valid` functions aren't quite valid. You can't check the `c !=i` part, because it'll make all checks false. Change the if statements to this:

```
if (v == rowcol[i][c] && v!=0)
```

and

```
if (v == rowcol[r][j] && v!=0)
```

also you need to change the `solver` a bit:

```
bool sudoku :: solver(int r, int c) {
   while( r < 9 && rowcol[r][c] !=0) {
    c++;
    if ( c>8) {
        c=0;
        r++;
    }
    if (r > 8) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  for (int i=1; i < 10; i++)
  {
    int nextrow, nextcol;
      if (row_valid (r, c, i)&& col_valid(r, c, i)&& panel_valid(r,c, i)) {
        rowcol[r][c]=i;
        nextrow=r; //save next row and col
        nextcol=c;
        nextcol++; //increment next col and row
        if (nextcol >8) {
            nextcol =0;
            nextrow++;
        }
        if(nextcol==0 && nextrow ==9) {
            return true; //then it's done
        }
        if (solver(nextrow,nextcol)) {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            rowcol[r][c]=0;
        }
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

This seems to work for me and give me an output of:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
2 1 4 3 6 5 8 9 7
3 6 5 8 9 7 2 1 4
8 9 7 2 1 4 3 6 5
5 3 1 6 4 2 9 7 8
6 4 2 9 7 8 5 3 1
9 7 8 5 3 1 6 4 2
```

Comment: It needs to be data-recursive at a minimum, in order to backtrack tentative solutions that turn out to be wrong.  Consider what needs to happen when the `for` loop completes without finding a valid entry to put in the current slot.

Comment: I updated my main post with the row_valid, col_valid, and panel_valid functions. Do you see anything wrong with it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't see the need for it to be recursive. Humans solve Sudoku by iterating thru all the fields and inputting obvious answers untill the board is full (by 'obvious' I mean there can be only one number in a particular place). For harder puzzles, you often end up just notting possible answers to a given 'tile' and then just fill the board starting from the places the answers HAVE TO be correct. Both of these methods are based on iteration.

Comment: @PawełStawarz True about how we solve sudokus, but as I said in my answer, you can do it much faster by using brute force (why would we use a computer otherwise??).

Comment: @PawełStawarz I'll take it it works then, and I shouldn't waste my time looking at the code? :)

Comment: @Noctis I provided the code, you can spend all the free time you want or even **test** it. But yes - you can also take my word, because it **does** work.

Answer (score 0):

As of your comment reply, Yes:

Code it properly.

Use methods as they should be used and name them properly.
Have `InitilalizeBoard` fill all zeros.
Have `SetBoard` put the start values on the board.
Have `SolveBoard` try to solve it.

It's a good programming habit to have each method do 1 thing, and make it's name clear.

Having said that, I did something similar a couple of years ago. It's much easier, faster, and takes less code to solve the sudoku with brute force approach using for/while loops, than doing it with recursion, or even coding it to be efficient and try to solve it like a human would (remove options that are obviously wrong and so on).

So, depending on your end result, you might want to code it appropriately ... (I did it to refresh my C++, so didn't care doing it the hard, long way first, and then doing it the short way).

Comment: I updated my code with the functions of checking row valid, col valid, and panel valid. Any idea if those are what is messing up?

Comment: @Mdjon26 notice the changes to your code for brevity. I think you should have the brackets in for/while loops, but in this case, where you ask people to look at your code, it's better to remove them so your code is shorter and easier to read. I'll look it it a bit later and see if i see anything obvious. Otherwise, try codereview.stackexchange.com :)